# Xarray dataarray idxmin() with a where() method returns all 'NaT' array

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a xarray data array containing values ranging from 0 to 34. The array is with 3 dimentions, time (daily data for 30 years), then lat and lon for the locations. It should be noted that for some lat-lon locations, all values are zero throughout the time dimension.

I would like to find out the dates of the first non negative occurrences and I suppose idxmin() or argmin() methods should do the trick. But if I apply these along the time dimension, I am getting all 'NaT' returned from idxmin() methods and argmin() method is encountering all-nan sliced.

I suspect it is due to the locations with no non-zero values. How to avoid this return of all 'NaT' by ignoring the locations of all zeros?

I have tried,

```
da.idxmin(dim='time') # this works but it takes the zero values into account

da.where(da>0).idxmin(dim='time') # it returns all 'NaT' array since da.where(da>0) returns a array where some locations are all nan values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this approach:

```
da_min_index = da.where(da > 0).argmin(dim='time')
if np.isnan(da_min_index).all():
    da_min_index = xr.DataArray(np.nan, dims='time')
```

Comment: As I mentioned, the argmin() method encounters the all-nan slice, i.e. ValueError: All-NaN slice encountered. So, this is not working.